# Code war not accepting my answer for exercise when it runs perfectly in console

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm doing an exercise on code wars:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/59342039eb450e39970000a6

I came up with the solution which works perfectly in Chrome console. Issue is that it's not being accepted by code wars and I can't figure out why. Below is the error I'm getting:

```
Test Results:
 Test Cases
 Log
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1:0x555efc554000]     2290 ms: Mark-sweep 580.4 (592.2) -> 580.4 (592.2) MB, 95.8 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[1:0x555efc554000]     2381 ms: Mark-sweep 580.4 (592.2) -> 580.3 (585.2) MB, 90.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[1:0x555efc554000]     2489 ms: Mark-sweep 580.3 (585.2) -> 580.3 (585.2) MB, 108.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x36e45eaa57c1 <JSObject>
    1: oddCount [/home/codewarrior/index.js:~5] [pc=0x3fab5460b26d](this=0xe983940c211 <JSGlobal Object>,n=0xe983940f199 <Number 7.68815e+15>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [/home/codewarrior/index.js:24] [bytecode=0x3a4c20cf0f1 offset=70](this=0xe983940c211 <JSGlobal Object>)
    3: /* anonymous */ [/runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:152] [bytecode=0x3a4c20c81f1 offset=145](this=0xe983940c211 <JSGl...
 STDERR
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I have to write a function that returns a number of positive odd integers. When I call the function I get exactly what they are asking for.

```
function oddCount(n){
  var result = [];
  for(var c=1; c<n; c++) {
    if(c % 2 !== 0) {
      result.push(c);
      }
    }
   return result;
  }
```

Comment: On the left side of codewars there's a few test cases. It should say which test case you've failed

Comment: please provide link for question ?

Comment: where does your code check if the number is possitive?

Comment: What is the requirement here? `oddCount(3)` returns `[1]` and `oddCount(5)` returns `[1, 3]`, so it's non-inclusive to the input but I don't know if that's intended or not.

Comment: The question is probably https://www.codewars.com/kata/count-odd-numbers-below-n/javascript. Why do you need a loop for this? Dividing n by 2 gives you the answer instantly.

Comment: @ggorlen i don't know if it's the same - that requirement only needs the *count*, while this implementation returns each number.

Comment: It may not be, but it has the same function header. Which others katas share this header? It seems likely that OP is misinterpreting the question.

Comment: @ggorlen in either case, it's unclear what OP is asking.

Comment: I don't disagree there, but I can't find any other katas matching the question, so I'm standing by my guess. Maybe we should send out a search party for OP.

Comment: The question is "Given a number n, return the number of positive odd numbers below n, EASY!" Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I think ggorlen is correct in that I am misinterpreting the question. I think I'm supposed to return the number of odd integers for n. *Hand to face*. Again sorry for the late reply. Gonna go back and make the necessary changes and I'll post again with results. Thanks everyone for the replies.

Comment: I'm back to say I definitely misinterpreted the question. All I had to do was add .length to my variable 'result'. Alot was going on in my head during the 2 hours I was stuck on this. I started doubting myself thinking I just wasn't smart enough. Please don't laugh as I know this is probably a no brainer exercise to most of you, but I am new to coding and code wars. But I got so much satisfaction knowing I solved it and feel if I just keep practicing I can get there one day. Haven't gone to school either, self taught. Thanks again to all with the quick replies.

Comment: Link to the question: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59342039eb450e39970000a6/train/javascript